# How to check email existence using emberjs email-existence?

Tags: ember.js, email-validation

Ember does give a link for email-existence.
But can somebody please explain how to use this API for checking an email whether it exists?

https://github.com/nmanousos/email-existence

Comment: You should probably contact the author of that API for support.  Questions asking about off-site resources are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't have much to do with Ember in the beginning. You have to create a node.js application and install `email-existence` package, then, you have to expose an API for Ember and send a request from client application to your backend.

Comment: Daniel, installation step is known via npm. What I am looking for is how to use the API in the JS code. I tried import EmailExistence from 'email-existence'; but that didnt help.